# Failed to open display error

Tags: macos, opengl, ssh, terminal, x11

I am having an error whenever I try to open an external display through sshing into a linux server. The error occurs in various contexts:

freeglut (./executable): failed to open display 'localhost:22.0' *** Program linking with openGL

(gedit:9741): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:22.0

Essentially anything that requires opening an external display results in the error. From searching on the internet, it has something to do with the display variable and it was originally just 0:0. However, I changed my local ~/.profile to include the line (DISPLAY=localhost:0.0; export DISPLAY) it showed the same error, but with localhost:x:0 rather than just 0:0.

I have xquartz installed, and I'm sshing with -Y flag set. I've tried the -X flag as well and still luckless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

X11 forwarding must be enabled on the SSH server on the Linux system as well. In /etc/ssh/sshd_config set

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

Don't mess with the DISPLAY variable yourself, the SSH server internally deals with doing the right authorization settings and will set DISPLAY accordingly.

Comment: The server that I was sshing into was hosted by the school and that file was private. Additionally, others are able to open external displays just fine.


The advice you give is great though, messing with the display variable was a mistake. Deleting the line I had in my ~/.profile for a reason I'm unsure of fixed it. The error was there prior to my adding it, and I did nothing else, other than run the bash script with it there and then delete it.

Comment: I'm currently facing the same problem but this did not resolve it

Comment: @Scarl: What's your systems' (both ends) configuration? (OS, SSH version, GPU on the machine you're sitting in front of, driver version installed on it).

Comment: @datenwolf I'm doing SSH  from a MAC to a windows XP machine. I keep on getting "ERROR: Failed to open display:"

Comment: @Scarl: Programs running on Windows usually don't know how to talk X11. The native MacOS UI also doesn't use X11. So you'd have to be in a constellation where: You're running XQuartz on the Mac, start SSH from inside a terminal using the X server, the SSH server on the Windows machine has been *built* with SSH support and last but not least try using a program that uses X11. The fact that you get the error "failed to open display" tells, that at least the last part is fulfulled.

Comment: @datenwolf that's interesting, is there a way to fix this issue though?

Comment: @Scarl: what's the output of `env | egrep 'XAUTHORITY|DISPLAY'` on either side of the connection?

Comment: @datenwolf are you referring to the XP I'm trying to connect to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96806/discussion-between-scarl-and-datenwolf).